# Select prenumbered mp3 file for playing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I have a number of mp3 file that are name01, name02 up to name10. The user will enter just the digits and then the mp3 will play.
For example user enters 02 the name02.mp3 will play.
I cannot name the files 01.mp3 02.mp3 etc as it is not accepted by Android studio.

Is it possible to use some thing like ->
int userinput

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(R.raw."name"+userinput);

Is it possible to do, any help much appreciated.